# css positioning two divs with text and two pictures

Tags: css, layout

What is the best way to make ,without negative margins, two divs and two pictures like these:

http://img97.imageshack.us/i/divsandpictures.jpg/

Comment: HAve you tried something on your own yet? Can we see it?

Comment: Yes, but there are problems under ie6.And it's not exactly what I want. http://rssreaderbg.net/zanas.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="yourimage.jpg" align="left" />
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="yourimage.jpg" align="left"" />
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div { margin:0 0 20px 0; }
p { padding:4px 0 0 30px; display:inline-block }
```

I believe this is the best way. At least, a minimal way.

Working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/J28YS/2/

**Revised**

http://jsfiddle.net/J28YS/6/

Comment: I fixed your version (OP said "images are the same width and height") http://jsfiddle.net/J28YS/4/ - but it now looks very much like @Paul's answer.

Comment: Ah, well that was the best way to reproduce what you had in your picture. To do it with a large amount of text will require a different method.

Comment: @lam3r4370 - Revised Version for wrapping.

Answer (score 3):

From your image I considered the following:

- the images are the same height, but may differ in width
- the images should be centered compared to each other
- the text won't wrap into more than one line
- you want the text to always start on the same line

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="{image source}" alt="{alternate text}" />
  </div>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item { 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrapper { 
  width: 200px; /* or whatever is the max width of the images */
  height: 100px; /* or whatever is the height of the images */
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item p {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

And a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/3RLrr/) with demonstration colors.

Comment: Oh,sorry.The images are the same width and height.And the text will be 2-3 lines

Comment: @lam3r4370: aha, in that case I think [tfbox’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297143/css-positioning-two-divs-with-text-and-two-pictures/5297289#5297289) is the one you want.

Comment: @lam3r4370 - next time please specify what you need. It is difficult waving around in the dark and making assumptions :). I will leave this here for future reference, somebody searching might find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Why without negative margins?

Anyway:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="div">
    <img src="grey.gif" width="60" height="60">

    <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="div">
    <img src="grey.gif" width="60" height="60">

    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.div {
    overflow: hidden;/* Contain the floated image */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.div img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

See http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/5297143/.